# Question about commercial use of generated JHipster apps

Tags: jhipster

I'd like to get some business apps up and running quickly with the use of JHipster, which seems like a solid approach; assuming it is allowed. Is the commercial use of a generated JHipster application allowed and if so, what are the proper steps to take in in order to not infringe upon any terms and conditions of open source?

I apologize if this has been asked previously.

I really just need to know how I can go about using an instance of a generated application for something other than an open-source project.

Sincerely,
Art

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many closed source applications originally  generated by JHipster. The generated project is fully yours.